# Adding metatags by javascript cant be seen in source code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meta-tags, applinks

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('head').append('<meta property="al:ios:url" content="' + appUri + '" />');
});
```

This code works fine but cant be seen in html source code, What is the best way to add metatags which can be seen in source code too.

**Update : As documented in the answer, We should not insert metatags by javascript, So by this I am just putting meta tags to html code directly**

Comment: You should not insert meta tag by javascript.

Comment: Add them to the HTML output and not using Javascript?

Comment: I can see the appended meta tag. [inspect it](https://jsfiddle.net/7m28nerx/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search engines get the source of your page, it doesn't look at what is rendered when javascript codes run. So any attempt to change meta tags by javascript is not efficient for search engines.